# How to place buttons left and on top of each other python3.4 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


def pressed():
    print("Button Pressed!")


def create_layout(frame):
    """
    Add two buttons to the frame.
    Both buttons should have the callback (command) pressed, and they should
    have the labels "Button1" and "Button2".
    Args:
      frame (tk.Frame): The frame to create the two buttons in.

    """
    button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button1", command=pressed)
    button1.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=20)

    button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button2", command=pressed)
    button2.pack(side=tk.TOP, ipadx=20)
```

There is my code above, It packs the button1 on top of button2 as intended but they are placed in the middle of the window, I need to place them to the left while keeping them on top of each other. How would I do this? This is just a exercise from my tutorial which I didn't get to and as you guys can see I have attempted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't definitely recommend you to use Tkinter. It's a very old tool,and it hasn't been updated, really. There are a lot more better Python UI frameworks than _that_

Comment: it is required for the tutorial

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde: I think that's bad advice. Tkinter is a fantastic toolkit, it comes with python and it has everything you need to learn how to do GUI programming. I wouldn't use it to write the next iTunes or Photoshop, but for 90% of the apps most people write, it's quite sufficient. It is a tremendous learning tool. The only downside is that it has some powerful features that no other toolkit has, which you may miss when switching to something else (though, to be fair, other toolkits have features Tkinter lacks, too...).

Comment: @BryanOakley it's always good to listen to different opinions. for me personally as a designer, its syntax and method structuring is very chaotic and follows very deficient rules. Compare it to frameworks for other languages, like visual C; or Cocoa for Swift. It has nothing to do.

Comment: And hopefully, in the future better UI frameworks will come, which help us programmers design more complex, yet efficient and intuitive UI's, with easier and better designing rules  and simpler code structuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pack method has several options, one of which controls how the widget is aligned in its space.

In your case, you want the `anchor` option. You want to anchor your widgets to the west (left) side of the container:

```
button1.pack(..., anchor="w")
button2.pack(..., anchor="w")
```

For a tiny bit more information see https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#packer-options